# pandas drop value in a group if values are multiple

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with an `id` column and a `quantity` column, which can be 0 or 1.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
{'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-01-01', 'quantity': 0 },
  {'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-02-01', 'quantity': 0 },
  {'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-09-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-10-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-01-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-02-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-02-11', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 3', 'date': '2017-09-01', 'quantity': 0 },
  {'id': 'thing 3', 'date': '2017-10-01', 'quantity': 0 },
])
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
df
```

[image]

If for a certain `id` I have both 0 and 1 values, I want to return only the 1s. If I have only 1s, I want to return all of them. If I have only 0s, I want to return all of them.

The way I do it is to apply a function to each group and then reset the index:

```
def drop_that(dff):
    q = len(dff[dff['quantity']==1])
    if q >0:
        return dff[dff['quantity']==1]
    else:
        return dff
    
dfg = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(drop_that)
dfg.reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

However, I implemented this just by brute-force googling and I really do not know if this is a good Pandas practice or if there are alternative methods that would be more performant.

Any advice would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```
# find the number of unique quantity for each thing
s = df.groupby('id')['quantity'].transform('nunique')


df[s.eq(1)                 # things with only 1 quantity value (either 0 or 1)
   | df['quantity'].eq(1)  # or quantity==1 when there are 2 values
  ]
```

Output:

```
        id       date  quantity
2  thing 1 2016-09-01         1
3  thing 1 2016-10-01         1
4  thing 2 2017-01-01         1
5  thing 2 2017-02-01         1
6  thing 2 2017-02-11         1
7  thing 3 2017-09-01         0
8  thing 3 2017-10-01         0
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on your logic, try `transform` with `max`, if max eq to original value we should keep,

```
#logic : only have 0 or 1  max will be 0 or 1 , 
#        if both have 0 and 1, max should be 1 we should keep all value eq to 1 

out = df[df.quantity.eq(df.groupby('id')['quantity'].transform('max'))]
Out[89]: 
        id       date  quantity
2  thing 1 2016-09-01         1
3  thing 1 2016-10-01         1
4  thing 2 2017-01-01         1
5  thing 2 2017-02-01         1
6  thing 2 2017-02-11         1
7  thing 3 2017-09-01         0
8  thing 3 2017-10-01         0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, that might be closer to natural language:

```py
(
    df
    .groupby("id")
    .apply(lambda x: x if x.quantity.unique().size == 1 
                       else x.query("quantity == 1"))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
#   id       date        quantity
# 0 thing 1  2016-09-01  1
# 1 thing 1  2016-10-01  1
# 2 thing 2  2017-01-01  1
# 3 thing 2  2017-02-01  1
# 4 thing 2  2017-02-11  1
# 5 thing 3  2017-09-01  0
# 6 thing 3  2017-10-01  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using rank:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['quantity'].rank(method = 'dense',ascending=False).eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
        id       date  quantity
2  thing 1 2016-09-01         1
3  thing 1 2016-10-01         1
4  thing 2 2017-01-01         1
5  thing 2 2017-02-01         1
6  thing 2 2017-02-11         1
7  thing 3 2017-09-01         0
8  thing 3 2017-10-01         0
```